# Contract not being initialized

Tags: solidity, truffle

Having issues with a contract creating another contract using Truffle dev environment. Here are my steps -

```
truffle console
var node = Node.deployed()
node.then(function(instance){node=instance})
var relay = node.createRelay()
```

Getting this response after `createRelay`:

```
{ tx: 
'0x5172bd954f72d31bb73278a10343ddfbd613c4938162b5ae9574b2e173271d03',
  receipt:
   { transactionHash: 
'0x5172bd954f72d31bb73278a10343ddfbd613c4938162b5ae9574b2e173271d03',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: 
'0xcae09bb248baf2bc0cd9065c629958336874c2ae8c5b1e5fbd5f867600d63c56',
     blockNumber: 40,
     gasUsed: 159039,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 159039,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [] },
   logs: [] }
```

As you can see, `contractAddress` is `null`.

Here are my contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
import "./Relay.sol";

contract Node {

uint public fee;
address public owner;
address[] activeRelays;

  function Node() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    fee = 10;
  }

  function createRelay () returns (address) {
    address relay = new Relay();
    activeRelays.push(relay);
    return relay;
  }
}
```

Relay:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Relay {
address public owner;

  function Relay() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function fundRelay() payable returns (bool) {

  }

  function releaseFunds () {

  }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing a step. Simple way forward:

**First**, `address[] public publicRelays; // easy access with free getter using "public"`

**Second**, it's normal to get a transaction hash when you submit a transaction. We don't expect a result. Ergo, we won't get the contract address that way.

Instead, wait for the transaction to be mined. At the outset, just watch your node/miner. When you're sure a block has been mined, then it follows that you should then be able to:

```
> var relay;
> node.publicRelays.call(0).then(function(response) { relay=response; });
> relay
0x123...
```

Meaning, 1) interrogate the `publicRelay()` getter and ask or row 0 (because it's an array). 2) Wait for the response ... 3) see the response.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Rob is totally right, just let me add why: Transactions return only transaction IDs. So even though you've set ` createRelay ` to return an address, you will indeed just get the tx ID back. Returning data from a function outside of the EVM works only with calls (reading), whereas functions within contracts can get data returned.